# html css js client-side editing

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there a way to modify html/css/js code on certain site client-side??
For example, Google Chrome Developer Tools allows editing css properties and values,
after pressing enter it shows modifications on screen.
i would like to edit css/js files as well.

Is there a tool (maybe extension) which allows it??

Thanks in advance!!

P.S.: i tried to save page, but that doesn't help...(it's total mess. too many dependencies
on site's folders...) .

Comment: I don't think there is a tool that lets you edit javascript on the fly. You can change CSS rules using the Developer Tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox. But not javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) it is what you need. Exist an addon extension for Firefox and Chrome.

Another possibility it is using a more permanent modification to keep in place (like for example I hate the new twitter redesign, and I am loading a my preference in styles) [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/)

If you look for permanent editing of files as JS have you tried [greasmonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for FF?

And just to show off the power of HTML5
http://html5demos.com/contenteditable
http://annevankesteren.nl/test/contenteditable-style.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can look at http://www.webputty.net/ too, but this is specific to css only (as far as I know).